# How do I check if a date is null from within a lambda expression and use todays date only if it is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, lambda

So I have two columns.  a `date_from` which will never be null and a `date_to` which can be null.

When it is null I want to use today's date instead of null.  When it is not null I want to use the date of the column.

Here is the lambda I am using.

```
serv_plus_Addons MarkupOnParts = db.serv_plus_Addons.Where(w =>  
    w.addon_name.ToLower() == "markup on parts" 
    && w.sdealer_number == sdealer_number 
    && w.date_to <= dtcontract_sale_date 
    && w.date_from >= dtcontract_sale_date
).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: use null coalescence `w.date_to ?? DateTime.Today`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use null coalescence [?? Operator (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)

```
w.date_to ?? DateTime.Today
```

which would mean that if  `date_to` is not `null` use `date_to` otherwise use `DateTime.Today`

another way is via

```
w.date_to != null ? w.date_to : DateTime.Today
```